# Can I reorder SATA port connections?

Tags: windows-7, sata, port

I currently have 5 SATA-Drives installed and Windows 7 installed.

I want to reorder the connections, ie connect alle the drives to different ports. Does this mess up anything in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean physically plug them into different ports on the motherboard? It should be fine just note you probably want to go into the BIOS after making the change and confirm the drives and the boot order is what you want.

Comment: Yes, physically plug them into different ports. Thanks alot!